# Clone clog output stream with C++

Tags: c++, clone, outputstream

In addition to `cout`, `cerr` and `clog` I want to have another output stream that is doing and manageable the same as `clog`, maybe called `debg`. I would like to use it for a library for its own (error/debug) output without affecting the standard output streams. They may be used by the program that is using the library.

For example I want to

```
// disable debg output
debg.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
// and enable it with
debg.clear();
```

Because these are system wide settings it should not also disable `clog` or one of the other default output streams.

I had a look at the different stream classes and some examples using them. The closest example I could find was to redirect the output stream. But that isn't what I need.

Is there a way to clone the `clog` output stream to have an additional output stream, maybe called `debg`, that do the same as `clog`, e.g. `debg << "alternative stream used" << std::endl;` that will also output to stderr?

Comment: There is not such way. `cout`, `cerr` and `clog` are streams to pipes that are created by a shell. Why `auto& debg = cerr` does not work for you?

Comment: @273K Is it really as simple as it seems? What if I disable `debg`? Can the program using the library still output to `cerr`?

Comment: What is *disable `debg`*? Could you please show a code or at least use terms of C++ standard library?

Comment: @273K I have added an example to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create an object of type `std::basic_ostream` called `debg` and give it a custom streambuf derived from `std::basic_streambuf` that clones its output to the same streambuf as `std::clog::rdbuf()` with whatever customization your special stream requires, if any.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But I have no practice doing it and can not find an example on the web. Could you help me with a code snippet to give an idea how it could be done in practice? It's already done with `clog`. Do you know where to find how it is coded?